# How to export fonts and colors from VS2008 to VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio

I have been forced to work in Visual Studio 2005 and would like to export my fonts and colors from Visual Studio 2008. However, VS2005 complains about wrong export document version. Is there any good way to do this besides manually changing each color and font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a tag in the exported file called "applicationIdentity" that is set to a value of "9.0" by 2008, change it to "8.0" and the file should import. I don't recall it causing any problems from settings that are 2k8 specific, but take a backup of your settings first!

UPDATE: Just looked in an export file and there is indeed a '<ApplicationIdentity version="8.0"/>' in a 2k5 file so it should be "9.0" in the 2k8 file (I haven't VS2k8 on my PC here to verify this beyond a doubt).